# Что такое хэш тег?

Tags: hashcode

Что такое хэш тег?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Хэштег (hashtag, не путать с кэштегом) — тематическая метка на
> [Твиттере](http://twitter.com), [вконташечке](http://vk.com) и
> аналогичных системах, содержащая слово
> или фразу, о которой идёт речь в
> записи.
>
> Хэштег должен начинаться с решётки(#) и не содержать пробелов,
> причём твиттер поддерживает хештеги,
> написанные кириллицей. Размещая хэштег
> в своей записи в твиттере или VK,
> пользователь как бы «помечает» запись,
> которая становится затем доступной в
> списке этого хэштега.
>
> Список всех твитов, помеченных данным хэштегом, доступен при нажатии
> на хэштег и содержит самые популярные
> твиты с этой меткой. В русскоязычном
> твиттере популярны хэштеги
> **#спасибопутинузаэто** и **#жалкий** (после визита на журфак МГУ Медведев
> получил этот хештег в подарок).